# How do I make my animated div to only expand outwards, so that the middle is staying in the same spot?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

DEMO of what it looks like right now: http://jsfiddle.net/2vVpt/180/

The jQuery code I'm using:

```
$("#blinkandresize").click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(300).fadeIn(300).fadeOut(300).fadeIn(300).animate({height: 400, width: 400})
});
```

Now how do I make this cirle expand outwards, and staying in the same place?

Comment: you have to animate the left/top property as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position your circle absolutely and then use the following code for an animated effect

```
$("#blinkandresize").fadeOut(300).fadeIn(300).fadeOut(300).fadeIn(300).animate({
    'width': '+=400px',
    'left': '-=200px',
    'top': '-=200px',
    'height': '+=400px'
  }, 600);
```

CSS:

```
#blinkandresize {
    position:absolute;
    top: 250px;
    border-radius: 1000px;
    left: 250px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #334;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2vVpt/182/

Comment: Thank you so much Void, really helped me out a lot!

Answer (score 0):

position it absolutely within a container

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="blinkandresize"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2vVpt/184/